# Oracle select: Fastest way to get total number of rows

Tags: performance, oracle, select, count, resultset

I am executing a SQL query which scans couple of tables with million of rows.
What I was trying to implement was my select query should return result only if the result set contains only one row.
I knew these two approches to do it:

1) Use group by and then 'having count( * )'

2) Use inner query which further uses 'count( * ) over'

But both of these approches would hamper the performance.
I would like to know, if there is any other faster approach to do this. Let me know if you require more information.
Thanks.

Comment: i assume you want just SQL, not PL/SQL (as select into from..) would satisfy this as 2+ rows = TOO_MANY_ROWS exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this for a pure SQL way.

```
select * 
  from (select c.*, count(*) over() cnt 
          from (select * from table where x = 'a' etc) c 
         where rownum <= 2) 
 where cnt = 1;
```

of course, if your query has order by, it will have to scan the result set anyway (correct indexing + perhaps first rows hint will help if that is the case.)

Comment: if your query has order by, remove that. Since you only want one row (or nothing) there is no need to sort anything.

Comment: Dazzal, You query does the trick :) But i would like to wait for more answers in order to select best answer. But yes your solution is really good!

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way would be to select the first two rows with a stopkey (and then throw away the result if there is more than one row, either client-side or by wrapping it into another SELECT).

Something like

```
SELECT * from (
   SELECT * from 
     THE_MASSIVE_QUERY_WITH_ALL_SORTING_REMOVED_BECAUSE_YOU_DONT_NEED_IT
) WHERE rownum < 3
```

This way you tell Oracle to stop once it finds the second row. No need to determine the actual count (which could take a lot of time).